# Python 3.8.2 / 2.7.9 cannot output UTF-8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a weird issue, I attempted all the suggested answers of this field but I'm probably missing something that should be very easy.  I have the following code:

```
def parseinvalid():
newfile = open('outputBlueTooth.txt', 'r')
print('Parsing Invalid')
for line in newfile:
    splitted = line.split("]")
    if len(splitted) > 6:
        if len(splitted[1]) > 2 and len(splitted[3]) > 2 and len(splitted[5]) > 2 and len(splitted[6]) > 2:
            oldvalue = splitted[5].split(',')[0]
            newvalue = float(oldvalue) * 0.70
            print('blue-laut]'+splitted[1]+']'+splitted[3]+']'+str(float(oldvalue))+']'+str(float(newvalue))+']'+splitted[6]+']\n\r')
```

and this string:   `Micro SD-Kartensteckplatz für MP3-MusikwiedergabeMicro SD`

Gets output from the print as `Micro SD-Kartensteckplatz fÃ¼r MP3-MusikwiedergabeMicro SD`

Even though the head the script starts with: `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-`

Comment: Why is this tagged python-2.7 when the code is Python 3 format?  The answer is different between the two major Python versions, and Python 2 is out of support.  Also, the `coding` declaration declares the *source code* encoding.  Your code is all `ascii` characters (a subset of the default `utf-8` of Python 3) so it has no effect.  Python 2's default is `ascii` so it also has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` only affects string literals in the code. It has nothing to do with any other strings in the code, namely strings read from files.

The most likely issue here is that you don't provide `encoding` to `open`, which does a very bad job at choosing a default encoding if it is not given one.

Change `open('outputBlueTooth.txt', 'r')` to `open('outputBlueTooth.txt', encoding='utf8')` (no need for mode `r` as it is the default one).

Comment: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, this was in python 2.7, in python 3.x specify the encoding in open works, thanks for your solution.